# Пунктуация в выражении

Tags: запятые

"Ты - дурак?" или "Ты дурак?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный вариант без тире.

В подобных вопросах тире не ставится.

Стандартный вопрос: "ты кто?". При замене на существительное в пунктуации ничего не меняется.

Пример из литературы (Елена Крюкова "Зимняя Война"):

*— Ты дурак?


— Да, дурак.


— Нет, ты скажи, ты совсем дурак?


— Как видишь.*

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, по известному правилу (о тире между подлежащим и сказуемым) тире не ставится, если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, однако у Розенталя на этот счет есть примечание, что тире возможно при интонационном подчеркивании.
Ученый приводит пример из В. Маяковского:
***Читайте! Завидуйте! Я — гражданин Советского Союза!***
Таким образом, во фразе "Ты — дурак?" вполне смотрится интонационное тире.
В то же время в предложении "Ты совсем дурак?" роль интонационной паузы играет наречие "совсем".

Comment: Я позволила себе подправить Ваш ответ. И оценить соответственно. Вот — в Вашу поддержку: **Берт Ригби, ты — дурак.**  https://www.kino-teatr.ru/kino/movie/ros/45698/annot/  Убрала только "частицу" из формулировки "наречие-частица", потому что  в значении усилительной частицы _совсем_ употребляется при отрицании. http://endic.ru/academic/Sovsem-59946.html

Comment: Спасибо, уважаемая Римма Михайловна, за замечание. Я чувствовал, что "совсем" синонимично "абсолютно, совершенно, бесспорно", однако подсознательно теплилась мысль, что есть в этом слове и какой-то элемент от частицы, ибо оно, как полагается частице, придает слову усилительный оттенок значения. Сожалею, что не было времени посмотреть словарь. Ваше скрупулезное внимание к слову восхищает меня!